# Can't install new Diawi link on my iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I am trying to install a new build on my `iPhone X` but its not installed there.  I am doing the same on my other iphones but its getting installed successfully.
Alternatively, i tried with `iphone X` simulator and it worked perfectly.

**iPhone specs:**

```
1.iphone 5c--->iOS 10 and Xcode 7.3
2.other devices--->iOS 9.3 and Xcode 7.3
```

Anything to be modified in the `iphone X` settings? 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please check that provisioning profile contains UDID of your iPhone-X.

Comment: How to provision UDID? i will try!

Comment: Please refer this link : https://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-New-Device-to-Your-Apple-Developer-Portal

Comment: after registration you can download new provisioning profile and use it for new builld

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, right. I found out the solution.

I tried the following.

1. Make sure you registered your UDID correctly and provisioning profile includes UDID of your device.
   This floowing link helped me get through.
   [wikihow.com/Add-a-New-Device-to-Your-Apple-Developer-Portal](http://wikihow.com/Add-a-New-Device-to-Your-Apple-Developer-Portal)
2. Some times, build number had occurred this issue. when you distribute next build, don't forget to increase the build number. For example, earlier build number was 2, you should update it to 3 next time.
3. Make sure you used provisioning profile for adhoc.

Hope this will helps.